# noob question on executing cron job

Tags: python, linux, cron

I have a cron job like the following:

```
07 14 * * 1-5 python /home/foo/cronscript.py
```

The script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = open('/home/foo/cronpass.txt','w')
    f.write('abc')
    f.close()
```

Checking the syslog I suppose the command did run, but with an error:

```
  Aug 29 14:07:01 ubuntuserver CRON[16490]: (www-data) CMD (python /home/foo/cronscript.py)
Aug 29 14:07:01 ubuntuserver CRON[16488]: (CRON) error (grandchild #16490 failed with exit status 1)
```

Question: what does the error means? Does it means an error occurred while trying to execute the script, or that there is an error in my script?

What could be the error?

Comment: Are you running this in a root cronjob, or from your regular user's crontab?

Comment: @im running it from www-data's crontab

Comment: And does www-data have access to the python script? Try running the script as www-data (`su -` to become root, then `su www-data` to impersonate www-data) and see what that does.

Answer (score 3):

The usual error with `crontab` tasks, is that the environment in which they run don't have all the env. vars. you're accustomed to. Maybe here, `PATH` is not set to all the usual directories, and cron does not find the executable `python`. You should write the full path to it. as follows.

```
07 14 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/python /home/foo/cronscript.py
```

Comment: Alternatively, add a shebang to your python script, e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env python` (on the first line), and call the script directly (you need to chmod +x it first though).

Comment: hmm for testing i did what @tdammers advised and set the file to a+x.. now exit status changed to 127

Comment: 127=file not found. you sure python is at `/usr/bin`?

Comment: another possible error might be that the script dosen;t have permission to read/write to /home/... try putting it to r/w in `/tmp` first